# Non-restricted Restler documentation

Tags: php, restler

In the restler documentation https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/tree/master/public/examples/_010_access_control it is said:

"This example shows how you can extend the authentication system to create a robust access control system. As a added bonus we also restrict api documentation based on the same."

However, try as I may, I cannot manage to produce an API documentation that is not restricted while having routes that are. I need to be able to expose all the API end-points even if a given instance of a resource needs authentication. I don't want to write separate documentation to list all the end-points as this seems self-defeating for an auto-generated documentation.

I see that each resource has a lock symbol in the explorer. However, I cannot manage to obtain a closed lock- either the lock is open, either the resource is not displayed.

Has anyone managed to create the authentication system without the added "bonus" of restricting api documentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the documentation of protected api is just a default. You can simply change it with

```
require_once '../../vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
use Luracast\Restler\Resources;

Resources::$hideProtected = false; //*  <-

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('MyApiClass');
$r->handle();
```

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer otherwise this question will show up in unanswered

Comment: I would like too but I don't have a good enough stackoverflow "reputation" to do that. Sorry.